# How to change a negative r2_score result from Keras code

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

So I am trying to develop a deep learning program, which can predict the quality of wine based as a regression problem. The dataset is from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/. I have read some tutorials but it is mainly based on https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/deep-learning-python.

This code is written and run on colab.research.google.com. It runs without any issues, however the r2_score is negative and I don't fully comprehend why we are using sometimes X_test and X[test] e.g. for predicting the r2_score etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py # export models in HDF5 format
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import optimizers
from keras import losses
from keras import metrics 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read in red wine data
# Read a comma-separated values (csv) file into DataFrame.
red = pd.read_csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep=';')

X = red.drop('quality', axis=1) # Isolate data # Drop specified labels from rows or columns. # same as ix[:,0:11]
Y = red.quality

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X) # Scale the data with `StandardScaler
# StandardScaler transforms data such that its distribution will have a mean value 0 and standard deviation of 1. 
# Each value in the dataset will have the sample mean value subtracted, and then divided by the standard deviation of the whole dataset.

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

NB_EPOCH = 20

# split up the data into K partitions / K-fold cross-validation
# Generate indices to split data into training and test set
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential() # Initialize the model
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=11, activation='relu')) # Add input layer 
    model.add(Dense(1)) # Add output layer 
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    #model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.SGD(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit(X[test], Y[test], validation_split=0.25, epochs=NB_EPOCH, verbose=1)

#history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.25, epochs=20, verbose=1)

mse_value, mae_value = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)

print("Mean Squared Error: "+ str(mse_value)) # quantifies the difference between the estimator and what is estimated
print("Mean Absolute Error: " + str(mae_value)) #quantifies how close predictions are to the eventual outcomes

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print("Test score:", score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

# generating the graph through matplotlib
# Plot training & validation mea values
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
plt.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_error'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_mean_absolute_error'])
plt.title('Model MAE')
plt.ylabel('MAE')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_pred = model.predict(X[test])
print("this is r2:" + str(r2_score(Y[test], y_pred)))

print(test)
print(X[test])
```

Answer (score 0):

reason for splitting data to train and test is really simple if you train your model with all of your data, your model would work better for your data ( because of seeing it before) but when you want to see how it work on new data it won't work well (doesn't generalize)
so you should put a part of your data away so you could test your model, see if it generalize well. and when you want to what is the prediction of a new set to see how your model works you could use x[test].
and when you are calculating your error (r2) it is (y[test]-y_pred) for each sample so it could be negative or positive ( you are checking the difference of what you have predicted and what you should have got so a negative r2 means you are predicting lower than mean value) you could use mse for check it too (it's better for regression problems)
something like this:

```
  MSE = np.square(np.subtract(Y_true,Y_pred)).mean()
```